# Stop animation of multiple UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have some dynamic webview and activity indicator.

All is working fine when webview is loaded. But if  i tried to stop the activity indicator after the loading is completed,  only one indicator is stop spinning not all.

So how can i solve this problem :

I am using following code

```
-(void)myMethod{

for (int i=0; i<count; i++) 
{
//Create webview one by one
webView.tag=i;

 //Create a activityindicator
activityIndicatorView.tag=i;

 [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
 [webView addSubView: activityIndicatorView]; 

[self.view addSubView:webView];
 }

 }


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{    
    if(webView.tag==0)
    {
        [activityIndicatorView setHidden:YES];   
    }
    else if (webView.tag==1)
    {
        [activityIndicatorView setHidden:YES];   
    }
    else if (webView.tag==2)
    {
        [activityIndicatorView setHidden:YES]; 
    }
    else if (webView.tag==3)
    {
        [activityIndicatorView setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are actually only loading data on one single web view instance. Your initial loop always uses the very same web view. And, likewise, you keep using and starting the very same activity-indicator instance. Just because you assign a new tag to it, it will not create a new instance for you.

Comment: so how can i achieve this functionality can you help me?

Comment: So do i have to create different webview and activityindicator one by one to achieve this functionality?

Comment: @user1227928 inside the loop create multiple instance and add indicator to them and place them on the view, set tag for every instance as you did; hope this helps you